# Using an argument of a function in normal mode in Vim?

Tags: function, arguments, vim

I have a Vimscript function defined like this:

```
function Cs(a, b)
    normal a:a|"cylr a:b|x"cP
endfunction
```

However, the intended action (do some crazy stuff with the arguments a and b in normal mode) doesn't work, instead it takes the first "a" as "append" and writes the rest of the line to the file.

How can I use arguments on a "normal" statement in Vimscript? I found no way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build up a string with the parameters in and execute it with the `:exec` statement.

e.g. something like this:

```
function Cs(a, b)
    exec "normal " a ":" a "|\"cylr " a ":" b "|x\"cP"
endfunction
```

Comment: You forgot to concatenate the strings with .

Comment: @Luc:  No I didn't.  The exec command will take any number of arguments and concatenate them together without needing to use `.`